# see element information by id with strapi and react

Tags: javascript, reactjs, database, strapi

I'm learning react with strapi.

I have elements in a database and I manage to display them all without any problem.

I would like that when we click on an element we see the information of this one.

So I retrieve the link id without problem and I manage to display the information except that it only works once. In fact, if I click on the second element I have an error message.

Here is the code

```
const Articles = ({animal}) => {
    const [error, setError] = useState(null);
    const [Animaux, setAnimaux] = useState([]);
    
    const { id } = useParams()
 
    useEffect(() => {
        axios
          .get(`http://localhost:1337/api/animaux/`+id)
          .then(({ data }) => setAnimaux(data))
          .catch((error) => setError(error))
      }, [id])

      if (error) {
        // Print errors if any
        return <div>An error occured: {error.message}</div>;
      }
      console.log(Animaux)
 return(
    <div>
      Id :   {Animaux.data.id}
      Nom : {Animaux.data.attributes.nom}
      
      Description : {Animaux.data.attributes.Description}
     
     
    
    <div key={animal.id} className="card" >
          <span className="btn btn-primary">Voir {animal.attributes.nom}</span> 
           </div>
     )}
     */}
        </div>
```

)

};

export default Articles;

Here is the result the first time :
[Here is the result the first time](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KKP5I.png)

The result that I have afterwards (after updating, then it does not come back at all)
[The result after](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fdVED.png)

I see that it returns me an empty array but I don't understand why

Many thanks to all for your future help.

Answer (score 0):

Data which you get from api returns empty array. In addition, you cannot access the object of the array without giving an index.

You can't use like that {Animaux.data.id}, you can return with map ;

```js
{
  Animaux.map(function(data,index){
    return(
      <>
        <p> id : {data.id} </p>
        <p> nom : {data.nom} </p>
        <p> Description : {data.Description} </p>
      </>
    )
  })
}
```

Comment: Thx a lot for your time and your answer ! I had tried this but I have this error :  Animaux.map is not a function

Comment: @MeganeLemaitre check then(({ data }) => setAnimaux(data)) line. maybe edit like then(({ data }) => setAnimaux(data.data))

Comment: Thank you very much, I already tried but it does not work either, I have the same error message. Could the problem be that I am displaying by ID and therefore only one element?

Comment: @MeganeLemaitre idk return what, but problem is there, so check it

Comment: I don't understand why the first time the information is displayed correctly and then not.

Maybe my method is wrong, I try to link strapi to react.

I get the element id with {id} us param , it works fine. I think I'm wrong in the display but I don't know how to fix this problem

Comment: Cause of problem, after first time render, you change the state (Animaux) with useEffect. So check it axios  method

Comment: When I display only ID it's ok, I think It's the root to display attributes that don't working.
{id: 2, attributes: {…}}
attributes:
Description: "Très joli petit chat roux, adorable "
createdAt: "2022-06-16T14:46:18.850Z"
nom: "Mégane"
publishedAt: "2022-06-16T14:46:50.154Z"
updatedAt: "2022-06-20T16:44:45.072Z"
[[Prototype]]: Object
id: 2
[[Prototype]]: Object

Comment: Thank you again for your answer, how do you think I can modify my Axios query? :/

Comment: And , if I do with fetch I have an error     const {loading, error,data} = useFetch('http://localhost:1337/api/animaux/' + id)
    if(loading) return <p>Loadgin</p>
    if(error) return <p>Error ouiiiin</p>

Comment: I do  const [{ data, loading, error }, refetch] = useAxios(`http://localhost:1337/api/animaux/${id}?populate=*`);
    if(loading) return <p>Loadgin</p>
    if(error) return <p>Error ouiiiin</p>
  and it's ok

Answer (score 0):

Can you trying using the optional chaining operator.

```
 return(
   <div>
     Id :   {Animaux?.data?.id}
     Nom : {Animaux?.data?.attributes?.nom}
  
     Description : {Animaux?.data?.attributes?.Description}
 
      <div key={animal?.id} className="card" >
         <span className="btn btn-primary">Voir {animal.attributes.nom}</span>    
      </div>

    </div>
```